# UnicodeDecodeError Persisting with JSON File

Tags: python, json, python-unicode

While loading a JSON file, a "UnicodeDecodeError" with the message "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte" repeatedly came up. After doing some digging, it's my understanding that the error means there are characters in the file that are not compatible with the UTF-8 encoding.

I tried to solve this my specifying the file encoding as "utf-8" when opening the file in Visual Studio Code. I also tried using the "latin1" encoding or the "errors='ignore'" parameter in the file opening statement but that also did not work.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

For context, this is exactly what I have so far:

```
import json
import os
import re

# Define the keywords
keywords = ["украин", "донбас", "донецк", "крым"]

# Get the absolute path of the Downloads folder
downloads_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads")

# Construct the file path
filename = os.path.join(downloads_path, "DiscussData-Words_of_Putin_&_Medvedev__Term_Frequency_Analysis-transcripts_ru_2023-01-16.json")

filtered_speeches = []

# Process the file
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    speeches = json.load(file)

    for speech in speeches:
        text = speech["speech"]
        if any(re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(keyword), text, re.IGNORECASE) for keyword in keywords):
            filtered_speeches.append(speech)

# Write the filtered speeches to a new file
output_file = os.path.join(downloads_path, "filtered_speeches.json")
with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(filtered_speeches, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

print("Filtered speeches saved to", output_file)
```

And this is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/ellaroberts/Downloads/filter_speeches.py", line 5, in 
> speeches = json.load(file)
> File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/**init**.py", line 293, in load
> return loads(fp.read(),
> File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
> (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 314000015: invalid start byte

Comment: Encoding issues can be hard to debug - I don't see anything immediately wrong with the way you're trying to read the file, though there are other ways to do it. One unfortunate possibility is that your file may be corrupted, EG if there have been newlines inserted between bytes that are part of the same codepoint. I'd probably try to narrow it down by first seeing whether Python can read the file as text, with no json involvement - try something like `with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f: f.read()` and see if it errors out.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried and am still getting the same error. I'm worried you might be right about the file being corrupted

Comment: Try using a command line tool like `cat` to see if there are any invalid chars in the file.

Comment: @TheTridentGuy Hi Thank you! Just tried that and got a bunch of weird symbols so safe to say the file may be corrupted. I'll try to reach out to the original researchers who made the file. I also tried `file -I`and confirmed that the original .json file is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: A few things you might look at if you want to try pinning it down further include using `od -c` to see the contents with any non-printable bytes replaced with their octal codes, and (to confirm or deny my wild-ish guess about newlines) `wc -l`.

Comment: @Peter the file is so long, it's been running for the last 10 minutes at least when I input 'od -c'. I quickly skimmed the original .json file, and finally realized that towards the end it looks something like this. ���S�y�"JRy���;��0ښ�0wCҠ/I��4%�. I have basically no programming experience, so just wanted to check this would be a good sign that it's corrupted

Comment: That's not necessarily a bad sign, given that your code implies it'll contain Cyrillic characters. You could do `head -c 120 | od -c` (or any other small/medium number, I just picked 120 more or less arbitrarily) to look at just those first n bytes - for a json file you'd expect to see it start with `{    "   s   p   e   e   c   h   e   s   "   :` before getting more into the structure.

Comment: And for what it's worth, I just did a quick check of the UTF-8 encoding of your keywords and observed that `д` is encoded as `b'\xd0\xb4'` - noting that the Python exception was for an unexpected `0xb4` byte at the _start_ of a character, that's at least consistent with my guess that it has unwanted breaks in the middle of the multi-byte encoding for a valid character.